# SOLR: How to get record with added on today's date in solr query

Tags: solr

I'm Inserting and updating records in SOLR on a daily basis.

I want to get only today's records from solr.

I checked for range query `ProductAddedOn:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]`

But it gives records from yesterday to today. I need only today's records.

Comment: Does `ProductAddedOn: NOW/DAY` work for you?

Comment: No.. I tried this.. :(

Comment: ProductAddedOn: [2020-02-18T00:00:00Z TO 2020-02-18T23:59:59Z]

Comment: this works!! so I need to create date dynamically from node js and pass it to query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `ProductAddedOn: [2020-02-18T00:00:00Z TO 2020-02-18T23:59:59Z]`.

This would give you the expected result.